# Difference between [[ expr1 || expr2 ]] and [[ expr1 ]] || [[ expr2 ]]

Tags: bash

Consider two conditional expressions `expr1` and `expr2`, for example `$i -eq $j` and `$k -eq $l`. We can write this in `bash` a number of ways. Here are two possibilities

```
[[ expr1 || expr2 ]]

[[ expr1 ]] || [[ expr2 ]]
```

I'm fairly sure I've seen recommendations here that the second should be preferred, but I can't find evidence to support this.

Here is a sample script that seems to demonstrate there is no difference:

```
for i in 0 1
do
  for j in 0 1
  do
    for k in 0 1
    do
      for l in 0 1
      do
        if [[ $i -eq $j || $k -eq $l ]]; then printf "1-yes\t"; else printf "1-no\t"; fi
        if [[ $i -eq $j ]] || [[ $k -eq $l ]]; then printf "2-yes\n"; else printf "2-no\n"; fi
      done
    done
  done
done
```

and output showing that both condition constructs produce the same result:

```
1-yes   2-yes
1-yes   2-yes
1-yes   2-yes
1-yes   2-yes
1-yes   2-yes
1-no    2-no
1-no    2-no
1-yes   2-yes
1-yes   2-yes
1-no    2-no
1-no    2-no
1-yes   2-yes
1-yes   2-yes
1-yes   2-yes
1-yes   2-yes
1-yes   2-yes
```

Is there any benefit to using one construct over the other?

For bonus points, same question but generalising to multiple conditions using `||` and `&&`. For example, `[[ expr1 && expr2 || expr3 ]]`.

Comment: With respect to why recommendations of this type are often given wrt. `[` or `test` (*not* `[[`), search for the `OB` tags (linked to the "obsolescent" definition) in the [POSIX spec for `test`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html). In `test`, there are some pathological cases where it can be impossible to tell if `(` or `)` is meant to be syntax meaningful to the test command or a string to be tested, so people who ignore the obsolescence markers and use that syntax can actually need the otherwise-obsolete `"x$foo"` practice; with `[[`, that isn't a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the recommendation you saw was for POSIX *sh* and/or the `test` command which doubles as the `[` command, rather than the `[[` construct which appeared in ksh (thanks Stéphane Chazelas for the tip) and is also used for example in bash, zsh and some other shells.

In most languages, like C, when a clause is already known to be true or false, there's no need to evaluate the remainder parts depending on the operation: if true not after a logical *or* following it, if false not after a logical *and*, etc. This of course allows for example to stop when a pointer is NULL and not try to dereference it in the next clause.

But *sh*'s `[ expr1 -o expr2 ]` construct (including bash's implementation) doesn't do this: it always evaluates both sides, when one would want only *expr1* to be evaluated. This might have been done for compatibility with the `test` command implementation. On the other hand, sh's `||` and `&&` do follow the usual principle: not evaluated if it won't change the result.

So the difference to note would be:

```
: > /tmp/effect #clear effect
if [ 1 -eq 1 -o $(echo 1; echo or-was-evaluated > /tmp/effect) -eq 1 ]; then
    echo true;
fi
cat /tmp/effect
```

which yields:

```
true
or-was-evaluated
```

Above, each `[` could have been replaced with `/usr/bin/[` which is an alias to the `test` command, used before `[` was made built-in to shells.

While the two next constructs:

```
: > /tmp/effect #clear effect
if [ 1 -eq 1 ] || [ $(echo 1; echo or-was-evaluated > /tmp/effect) -eq 1 ]; then
    echo true;
fi
cat /tmp/effect
```

or

```
: > /tmp/effect #clear effect
if [[ 1 -eq 1 || $(echo 1; echo or-was-evaluated > /tmp/effect) -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo true;
fi
cat /tmp/effect
```

Will only yield `true` and leave `effect` empty: `||` behaves correctly, and `[[` corrected this issue too.

---

UPDATE:

As @StéphaneChazelas commented, I missed several differences related to the initial question. I'll just put here the most important one (at least to me): priority of operators.

While the shell will not considere precedence:

```
if true || true && false; then
    echo true
else
    echo false
fi
```

yields (because there is no precedence and thus first `true || true` is evaluated, and then `&& false`):

```
false
```

inside `[[ ]]` the `&&` operator has precedence over `||`:

```
if [[ 1 -eq 1 || 1 -eq 1 && 1 -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo true
else
    echo false
fi
```

yields (because `1 -eq 1 && 1 -eq 0` is grouped and is thus the 2nd member of `||`):

```
true
```

at least for *ksh*, *bash*, *zsh*.

So `[[ ]]` has improved behaviour over both `[ ]` and direct shell logical operators.

Comment: Note that `[[...]]` comes from ksh and is also found in zsh (and a limited one in busybox sh).

Comment: I'll correct the answer (by removing bash) thanks

Comment: `[ x -o y ]` doesn't have to evaluate both side. While GNU `test` or the `[` builtin of `bash` do, you'd find with `strace zsh -c '[ x -o -f /x ]'` that `[` doesn't try to stat() `/x`. Same with `mksh`. But it's true that `-o` and `-a` are severely broken, can't be used reliably and are deprecated by POSIX.

Comment: One difference is that inside `[[...]]`, `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, while outside they have equal precedence. Compare `ksh -c '[[ x || x && "" ]]'` vs `sh -c 'true || true && false'`

Comment: Note that the standard `[` / `test` utility doesn't have a `==` operator. The equality operator is `=` (note that inside ksh's `[[...]]`, `=`/`==` are not equality operators, but pattern matching ones).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I added the most blatant difference you mentioned: precedence

Comment: It's the other way round. `&&` has precedence over `||` inside `[[...]]` (or `((...))`) but not the `&&` and `||` shell operators. `[[ x || y && z ]]` is `x || (y && z)` while `x || y && z` is `(x || y) && z` (operators evaluated left to right without precedence). Similar to how `*` has precedence over `+` (`1 + 2 * 3` is `1 + (2 * 3)`) but `+` and `-` have same precedence.

Comment: If `&&` has precedence over `||`, then it should be `true || (true && false)`, instead of `(true || true) && false`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas and Prvt_Yadv indeed I got it all wrong. Correction done.